# Overlook AWS credentials from env and instead use IAM role attached to node_group of EKS to push msgs to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-sqs, botocore

Problem: I have some downstream services which needs to push msgs to sqs using my python package but boto3 uses the credentials defined in their respect env instead of using IAM role of node_group.

I am looking for an alternative to bypass creds from env and use iam role attached with node_group to push msgs.

How can i achieve this?

If the env is unset, then it is working fine.
(Also going via profile based approach, not able to set profile at node_group level)

And we dont want to go via assumeRole.